# Customizing shortcuts in 2.8+ vs 2.79

Tags: shortcut, customization

In 2.79 I have the following keyboard shortcuts assigned for Edit Mode:

- Vertex Select: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>
- Edge Select: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>
- Face Select: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>

<sup>Note: I'm using "Emulate Numpad", so I register a shortcut as Numpad 1 instead of 1, for example.</sup>

Here's what the key binding that controls that in **2.79** looks like:

[image: Blender 2.79 Vertex Select Keyboard Shortcut]

And here's what I tried in **2.90** that *isn't working*:

[image: Blender 2.9 key binding not working]

I believe it has to do with the RNA field not existing in 2.8+ but I'm not sure how RNA works. What would be the way to do this in newer versions of Blender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems that need to be solved:

1. The shortcut you're attempting to assign is already in use for the viewport navigation. You may want to change these so you're still able to use them with a different key binding.
2. The identifier for the operator is not correct, but creating a new shortcut isn't necessary since the mode selection already exists in the default keymap. You only need to adjust the key binding from the regular <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> keys to the numpad ones.

In order to solve problem 1):

1. Open the keymap preferences
2. Switch the filter method to *Key-Bindings*.
3. Search for "Numpad"
4. Scroll down to find the *3D View* section and adjust the shortcuts that use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>. (If on a Mac there will also be <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 2</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>, in which case either the Ctrl or Cmd set can be deactivated, freeing up some shortcuts.)

[image: View Axis keyboard shortcuts when viewed on a Mac]

In order to solve problem 2):

1. Open the keymap preferences
2. Switch the filter method to *Name*
3. Search for "Select Mode", the identifier for the operator is `mesh.select_mode`.
4. Adjust the key binding to your liking.

[image: Reassigning the Mesh Select Mode Shortcuts]

Comment: Thank you so much! You've helped me migrate from 2.79 to 2.9. I'm finally reimplementing all of my shortcut customizations, and this was an important one. 2.9 is feeling a lot more comfortable now! (BTW, Ctrl on macOS *also* triggers the back views, so I just left those as they were, and remapped the Cmd versions which were redundant anyway - perfect!)

Comment: I added some screen shots to your answer, along with additional details for Mac users. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Mentalist Not at all, I think the screenshots and Mac specific information are a nice addition.