# Can these hotkeys be edited?

Tags: interface

I'm not a giant fan of moving the hand about the keyboard. "i" for example is a gross key and requires to look down. Am I able to redefine these keys? I'm asking so I don't spend ages trying to find them in the hotkey manager.

I would much prefer keys that are like 1,2,3/ qwer/ zxc
Cheers!

**updated:** It's not the inset I'm looking to add/change hotkey. it's the sub menu hot keys (when you are modifying the inset). **O = Outset | B = Boundary | I = Individual** I am not a fan of these hotkeys, they are not useful for a power user.
[image]

Comment: It's not the inset I'm looking to add/change hotkey. it's the sub menu hot keys (when you are modifying the inset). O = Outset | B = Boundary | I = Individual

Comment: Although you can, some of the shortcuts already have those keys, you might need to map them too https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193094/customizing-shortcuts-in-2-8-vs-2-79

Comment: Sorry, just out of curiosity: is there a reason for this interest in the _Inset_ tool? Some new tutorial using it? Because the question how to change these hotkeys came up three times or more in the last two or three weeks... maybe CG Cookie's "Blender Basics 13"?

Comment: O and I are disgusting keys, anything that requires looking down is idle wasted time. It may sound nuts but time is time.

Answer (score 0):

These keys are builtin, in the source code.

For instance, you can see [here](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/d0ef66ddff58065dbda08d32c06ef3157ff6487d/source/blender/editors/mesh/editmesh_inset.cc#L536C19-L536C19) how is handled "(I)ndividual" from the inset operation.

> ```
> case EVT_IKEY:
>   if (event->val == KM_PRESS) { ...
> ```

And `EVT_IKEY` is:

> EVT_IKEY = 0x0069, /* 'i' (105). */

Comment: I'm guessing I can't change then, I have a work-around that will work for me until I can. Ty for help!